# $wpdb->get_results not accepting variable in query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have the following in my functions.php file. I'm trying to return a metavalue(s) for a custom post.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'a_new_post', 10, 3 );
function a_new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
    return;

if ( 'post' == $post->jobman_job )
    return; // all of the above is just to trigger the below when my custom post is published

global $wpdb;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$meta_key_value = 'data19';
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = %s", $post_id, $meta_key_value);
var_dump ($result); // I'm getting NULL
}
```

When I use a different query and hardcode the values for $post_id and $meta_key_value into it... I get my result as expected. For some reason, the above query will not accept my variables! Can anybody assist?

Comment: If `$meta_key_value` is a string, doesn't it have to be enclosed in single quotes within the SQL?

Comment: Thanks Turophile but I did some more testing and I found that the query is working and displaying NULL 'correctly'. My problem is that at the point in time when I'm running the function that calls my query, the value I'm searching for hasn't been saved to the table. I need to do more research to see how I can get around that.